# The Silverlight how to use text editor?

Tags: image, silverlight, editor

I have a silverlight App. i need to use text editor which can insert pictrue and format text,just like the **FCKEditor** in Asp.net Web App.So which tools can i used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally we use the DevExpress RichText Editor, works pretty well
http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/Rich_Editor/

Comment: wow,it is not free, if exchage the PC,then need to reinstall this.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight Text Editor is avaible in silverlight 4 and above

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426926%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is the MSDN aritcle with sample sourcecode

Comment: Yes ,I see this,but there are so many codes,it is not easy to use